# Bean Validation + Database Access + Assertion

Tags: java, dao, bean-validation

I'm confused about a situation. Imagine a class like Person:

```
@Entity
class Person {
    @NotBlank(message="Some message")
    @Column(name="ssn", nullable=false, unique=true)
    String ssn;
    ...
}
```

Well, `ssn` must be unique, and I can do that by using the `unique=true` statement, but in order to show some message for users an assertion would be nice:

```
@AssertTrue(message="SSN is already in use.")
public boolean isSsnAvailable() {
    // database query
}
```

Do you guys think that's a good practice? For me is a little bit weird, because seems that entity is becoming too complex by adding database access to it.

I thought about two other possibilities:

1. Create a custom validator with an annotation like `@Unique`.
2. Create a transient attribute named `ssnAvailable` that would be filled by a PersonService.

Comment: Wow. Don't store SSN in plain text. Please hash them first using a safe one-way hashing algorithm

Comment: Is the message that you get back from that validation not satisfactory?

Comment: @flakes That's just an example. It could be a color code from a color palette or a word from a dictionary.

Comment: @psi_ Got it! Better safe than sorry! :)

Comment: @Makoto As I said to Ogbe, I have a form and I'd like to put the friendly message pointing to the input, just like when it's blank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to think *in the domain*. Is a `Person` responsible to check if one of its attributes is unique among all `Persons` there are? No, it's not and it should not possess the ability to do so.

That's what a `Service` typically is for. It is perfectly valid to run a query that searches for a Person with a particular `SSN`. In a `PersonService` the signature could look something like this:

```
 public boolean isSsnPresent(String ssn)
```

The unique constraint doesn't help you if you want to check if a `SSN` exists *before* you try to save the Person to the database.

Comment: Yes! That's what I was thinking, because it seems weird to think that an object could 'validate itself', and that's exactly what I'm trying to do: check if there is already an object with that ssn before trying to save it.

Comment: Great. But not to be misunderstood: "Validating itself" is something your entity (Person) is allowed to as long as it concerns itself. For instance, if you have a method like _updateEmail()_ in your _Person_ class, it is ok to check if the email has a correct syntax in order to keep the _Person_ in a valid and consistent state. I won't go too far here, there are several approaches, catchword: anemic and rich domain models. Quite interesting to read up on that.

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is catch the unique constraint violation exception that is thrown and throw your own custom exception or return the proper message you want... If the Exception thrown is not directly related to the unique constraint violation, you could get the cause exception using

```
e.getCause()
```

then change if it is a unique constraint violation and return a proper message.

Comment: I haven't tried this one. I have a form and I'd like to put the message pointing to the ssn input, for example, just like happens when it is blank.